# How to advance the selected option via button click (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I have a select menu with dynamic options.
the select has an `.on"change"` attached that redirects to the corresponding page.

now i want "Next" and "Previous" Buttons.

How can i advance (or step back) in the options, so that the change event fires?

I tried

```
$('#nextTipButton').unbind().on("click", function() {
    $('#hintSelect option:selected').nextSibling.focus();
});
// Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'focus' of undefined
```

and

```
// the same, but with an added [0]
$('#nextTipButton').unbind().on("click", function() {
    $('#hintSelect option:selected')[0].nextSibling.focus();
});
// nothing happens at all
```

the selector is correct, it `console.log`s just fine. but i don't know how to get the buttons to work
is there another way? is this wrong? how can i make it work?
thanks

Comment: You could trigger the change event on the next option `.trigger('change')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can increment the `selectedIndex` property of the `select` itself. Try this:

```
$('#nextTipButton').unbind().on("click", function() {
    $('#hintSelect')[0].selectedIndex++;
    $('#hintSelect').change();
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/69Lwuz20/)

If you want to ensure the index cannot exceed the number of options you would need to use this:

```
$('#nextTipButton').unbind().on('click', function() {
    var $select = $('select');
    var index = ++$select[0].selectedIndex;
    $select[0].selectedIndex = index % $select.find('option').length;
    $select.change();
})
```

Also note that you can remove the need to `unbind()` the events on the element each time by using a single delegated event handler:

```
$(document).on('click', '#nextTipButton', fn);
```

Comment: DOES increment the selected (shown) option 
but DOES NOT trigger the change event

Comment: You need to trigger the event manually when changing the option programmatically - see my update

Comment: it works with change(), thanks! (even though that index assertion is pretty bulky :/ )
would you mind explaining that delegated event handler thing real quick? i was wondering about exactly that 10 minutes ago and wanted to know (and understand) how i can do that.
it looks like it would do the same, just with a named function? how is that different?

Comment: With your current method you're presumably removing the click handler from all elements, then reattaching it to all elements again everytime a new button is added to the DOM. With a delegated event handler you set the event handler on a parent element once, and it will automatically catch events raised on any dynamically appended children matching the selector you provide. It saves time and makes the code more simple.

Comment: oh and could you explain your index assertion? i don't think i understand why you `index % length` (or why that makes sure the index keeps inside the boundaries)

Comment: That's the modulo operator: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder_()

Comment: yeah i know that... but why does it limit the indexes? :D

Comment: never mind, i googled it and caught up about the powers of modulo ;) thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should put the $.on('change') event on the select tag, not on the option tags. Then if you use back and next shortkeys or buttons and change the option, it'll actually fire the change event.

To answer your actual quesiton though, any event that is registered to a DOM element with the $.on() function can be triggered by using the $.trigger() function. So call $.trigger("change") on the desired element you want to trigger the event for.

Comment: the on('change') was actually on the select, edited it, sorry.
(still it didn't fire..)
i'm gonna try trigger

Comment: $('#hintSelect option:selected')[0].nextSibling.trigger('change');   => $(...)[0].nextSibling.trigger is not a function

am i missing something?

Comment: You need to call the trigger event on the element you registered it to, i.e. the select tag: $(" #hintSelect).trigger('change')

Comment: ohhh ok. so that's actually the same as $('#hintSelect').change(); from Rorys answer i guess?
thanks

Comment: Yes exactly, though it might be a personal choice, I usually prefer using the $.on() to register and $.trigger() to activate in order to avoid confusion for the human eye.